# Getting a covid test while transiting through Frankfurt or Zurich

Tags: transit, international-travel, covid-19, frankfurt, zurich

Due to the current Canadian restrictions travel restrictions for individuals in Omicron hotspots, they will need to **"Obtain, within 72 hours of departure, a valid negative COVID-19 molecular test in a third country before continuing their journey to Canada"** as stated here: https://www.canada.ca/en/public-health/news/2021/11/government-of-canada-introduces-additional-measures-to-address-covid-19-omicron-variant-of-concern.html

To not have to enter a country and deal with potential quarantine issues due to being in an area with a variant of concern, it looks like both Zurich and Frankfurt have covid testing inside the airport (https://www.flughafen-zuerich.ch/en/passengers/news/corona/general-information and https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/flights-and-transfer/covid-19/coronavirus-testing-at-the-airport.html respectively).

I've asked Canadian Foreign Affairs and they recommend Frankfurt, but I've been unable to confirm if the tests are able to be done in the international areas of the airport. Zurich is a bit more clear in that it is in a transit area, but on their map it appears to be behind a customs gate.

For Frankfurt, is there testing in transit areas or only outside the transit areas? And is there any information about where exactly these tests are conducted (i.e. international areas)? Has anyone had experience with them?

EDIT: I've contacted Frankfurt and the test providers, and they've been unhelpful, only saying to contact the medical center. The medical center doesn't have a number only email, but they have yet to respond.

EDIT 2: I've added an answer since I've gotten a lot more information between asking this question and now.

Answer (score 3):

In Zürich the airside testing centre is at the transit hotel, that is connected to concourse D, which is Non-Schengen. So you do not need to enter the country to get there.

The only wrinkle is that if your flights are from concourse E that you will have to pass through security each time. ZRH does not have a clean path from D to E, so you always need to go through security. But both D and E are Non-Schengen..

Answer (score 3):

*I've made this an answer in the hopes of getting others home.*

I've called Global Affairs Canada again, and they still advise Frankfurt based on previous travelers' experience. They told me to book with Lufthansa as they will deal with it. I've called Lufthansa and they stated the medical center in Frankfurt has a unit inside the international transit area of the airport thus allowing a PCR test without having to enter Germany.

Unfortunately there's no way for me to double confirm this as calling Frankfurt Airport itself has been unhelpful and I'm still awaiting an email sent to the medical center at Frankfurt.

Additionally, for those in South Africa, an exemption has been made, until the 13th of December, to not require the second PCR test if taken within 48 hours, fly through Frankfurt, and if the test was done by an accredited lab (more information here: https://www.ctvnews.ca/health/coronavirus/canada-introduces-temporary-exemption-for-stranded-travellers-in-south-africa-1.5694316)

I've asked Global Affairs and they have confirmed that this is **only for those in South Africa and not in the dozen other countries affected by the travel restrictions.** For everyone else in affected areas, you will still need a PCR test at a 3rd country.

Answer (score 2):

There are two test centers at FRA, Centogene and EcoCare. I personally know that Centogene is behind the customs gate and EcoCare is in Terminal 1/2. Have you tried calling EcoCare? They have a phone number and email address at their website https://flughafen-frankfurt.ecocare.center/en/
E-mail: direct-support@ecocare.center

Telephone: +49 211 387 895 73

Comment: Thanks for that, I did call them and they said they're behind customs. They told me to contact the medical center, but they don't have a number. I sent an email and didn't get anything back. I tried calling the airport itself, but they said they don't have any information about the medical center, which is just frustrating.

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking but "behind"  can be easily misunderstand depending on your reference point. Behind as seen from where? Better terms could be "airside vs landside", "in the transit area, outside the transit area" "in the secure area or outside the secure area"

Comment: To clarify, it meant that you would have to leave the international transit area, thus going through customs since you would have to enter Germany to visit them. Thus they are "behind customs".